# vector iterators incompatible when i have collision detection

Tags: c++, opengl

so i have DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible"); whenever i have collision detection between blackHole & planet. but when i have collision detection between anything else like asteroid & planet or blackHole & asteroid, then its work with no problem the code is basically the same but yet with this one i have crash

```
//Blackhole& Planet Collide
for (vector<Entity*>::iterator it = gameEntities.begin(); it < gameEntities.end(); ++it) // This loop usses an iterator (google c++ iterator) to go through all game entites objects
{
    BlackHole* blackHole1 = dynamic_cast<BlackHole*> (*it); // As the iterator is of generic type Entity we need to convert it to a type we can use, Ball. Dynamic cast performs the conversion only if the entity is actually a Ball otherwise it gives back a null pointer
    if (blackHole1 != nullptr) // we check if the conversion was successful
    {
        for (vector<Entity*>::iterator it1 = gameEntities.begin(); it1 < gameEntities.end(); ++it1) // and we iterate on the remaining elements in the container
        {
            if (it != it1)
            {
                Planet* planet = dynamic_cast<Planet*> (*it1); // we convert the remaining element
                if (planet != nullptr) // check if the conversion happended
                {
                    // collision detection: black hole & planet
                    if (blackHolePlanetCollision(*blackHole1, *planet))
                    {
                        blackHole1->increaseMass(blackHole1->getRadius(), planet->getRadius());
                        delete *it1;
                        it1 = gameEntities.erase(it1);
                        //--it1;
```

any idea what is wrong with it? with any other collision this code works

Comment: Are you running the same N^2 algorithm for all the types of collisions (black hole/planet, planet/asteroid, ...)? Maybe you could refactor your code to something like: `for (auto & it_a : gameEntities) { for (auto it_b = ++it_a; it_b != gameEntities.end(); ++it_b) { deal_with_collision(it_a, it_b); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it1 = gameEntities.erase(it1);
```

Here you have correctly reset `it1` after erasing from the vector (which potentially invalidates existing iterators) … but you did not do the same for `it`, which is now potentially invalidated.

When it *is* invalidated and you later try to compare it against the new `it1`, your standard library implementation has caught the bug and is trying to tell you the comparison is invalid. In a release build I'd expect this to just silently do weird things.

Comment: from my understanding you want me to add: it = gameEntities.erase(it); but the error changed into  vector erase iterator outside range

Comment: @maniekv16: No, that would be erasing another element. I don't know what the solution is I'm just saying you need to review your algorithm because at the moment you're invalidating `it` when you erase `it1`.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: fix it just had to add it = gameEntities.begin();

Comment: @maniekv16 _If_ you want to start the outer loop again. Don't just guess - think it through.